# Ошибка в Gradle

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста что за ошибка у меня.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 16.0.1.

Вот мой код в Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.test.app1"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 33
        versionName "1.5"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:12.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Уже разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Все оказалось просто.. Прописал в Gradle

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```